# nvarchar data type to a datetime SQL query

Tags: sql-server, datetime, nvarchar

I have 2 tables `ServiceType` AND `Services`.

`Service` table structure

```
    ServiceID          int           Unchecked
    Service_TypeID     int           Unchecked
    Last_performed     date          Unchecked
    Frequency          nvarchar(50)  Unchecked
    Freq_Duration      nvarchar(50)  Unchecked
    Freq_Mileage       nvarchar(50)  Unchecked
    Remin_frequ        nvarchar(50)  Unchecked
    Remin_duration     nvarchar(50)  Unchecked
    Remin_Mileage      nvarchar(50)  Checked
    Next_due_datetime  datetime      Unchecked
    Next_due_mileage   nvarchar(50)  Unchecked
```

`ServiceType` structure is

```
Service_TypeID  int             Unchecked
Service_Type    nvarchar(50)    Unchecked
```

Sample data

```
ServiceID   Service_TypeID      Last_performed  Frequency   Freq_Duration   Freq_Mileage    Remin_frequ Remin_duration  Remin_Mileage   Next_due_datetime   Next_due_mileage
3             2                 2012-12-01      6             month(s)       1000              1          day(s)          10            2013-03-10              1000
```

and I want data like this:

```
ServiceID   Service_TypeID      Last_performed  Service Frequency    Next Service      Create Reminder 
3             2                 2012-12-01      6 month(s)  1000     2013-03-10 1000    1 day(s) 10
```

For this I try this query:

```
select  
    Services.ServiceID,
    ServiceType.Service_Type,
    Last_performed
    Services.Frequency+''+Freq_Duration+''+Freq_Mileage as [Service Frequency],
    Services.Next_due_datetime+''+Next_due_mileage as [Next Service],
    Services.Remin_frequ+''+Remin_duration+''+Remin_Mileage as [Create Reminder]
from 
    Services
inner join 
    ServiceType on ServiceType.Service_TypeID = Services.Service_TypeID
```

but I get this error:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: you can not directly concat nvarchar and date type you should us Convert function for date conversion after that you can concat it with nvarchar type.

Comment: but why i use date convert to date when there is already data type is datetime?

Comment: Services.Next_due_datetime+''+Next_due_mileage  here first column is of datetime and second is of datetime thus you have to change datatype to varchar of firstcolumn and same for the rest.

Comment: Next_due_mileage  is varchar not date time @m.kudi

Comment: sry my mistake second one nvarchar.

Comment: just for your information: just like operator precedence there is a concept called operand precedence where operands are converted to a type depending on precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using concat

```
 concat(Services.Frequency,' ',Freq_Duration+' ',Freq_Mileage) as [Service Frequency]
```

Else need to use cast or convert to varchar for integer

Comment: ok spelling mistake.. but this show result like this 6month(s)1000  so how i add space between 6 , month(s) and 1000